# Can't start forge-cli

Tags: javascript

I installed [forge-cli](https://github.com/ArcBlock/forge-cli) successfully on my Mac, But it hangs for about 20 minutes when I start it, without any output.

I tried for several times, still failed. I don't know what happened, and what should I do.

Reproduce:

```sh
forge init
forge start
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what happened without any detail output, you can use `debug` mode to get more details:

```sh
forge start --dry-run
```

By the doc: https://github.com/ArcBlock/forge-cli/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-to-debug-when-forge-start-failed